# What happens when a local variable is assigned to global object?

Tags: javascript

Please ignore that this can be re-written without variables. It's just to have a simple example.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.body, b = function() {console.log(1)};
    a.onkeydown = b;
};
```

I know what happens: it works. But how?

If `b` was a global variable, the interpreter would store a reference to it. In this example, does the interpreter store a reference to the local variable, only to replace it, with what I assume is a copy of the function, when the local variable is destroyed? Or is the reference to the local variable still stored somewhere behind the scenes, and is then re-purposed?

Comment: I actually can't get this to work .. how can you trigger `onkeydown` on `document.body`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions (and other objects) are always passed by reference. `b` does not contain the function, rather it points to it. When you assign `a.onkeydown = b`, you are making `a.onkeydown` point to the same function object. Then the function ends, so the local `b` variable is destroyed but the function it points to is still there - it would only be removed by the garbage collector if there were nothing else pointing it to it.

Comment: So basically this can also be read as `a.onkeydown = b = function() {console.log(1)}`, and when `b` is destroyed, it makes no difference because the function is already also assigned to `a.onkeydown`, correct?

Comment: @Kolink [Functions (and other objects) are *not* passed by reference](https://github.com/ajcrites/Pass-By-Value/blob/master/src/pass-by-value.js)

Comment: @ExplosionPills That script proves nothing. The parameter is being masked by the local variable, so the one in the global scope is completely unaffected by the function... I fail to see how that script proves anything other than that local variables mask parameters.

Comment: @Kolink check again; I *just* updated it so that a local variable is not declared in memory (i.e. it uses the parameter)

Comment: You're still creating a new object and assigning the variable to point to it. The script now proves that JavaScript passes *pointers* by "value", but the object itself is still [passed by reference](http://jsfiddle.net/EvBTG/).

Comment: @Kolink you're missing the point.  If the object was passed by reference then in my original function the object would be overridden because the reference would be the same variable.  Creating a new object *is the point*.  In fact, object references are passed by value.  You can see an example of "pass by reference" (sort of) here: https://github.com/ajcrites/Pass-By-Value/blob/master/src/pass-by-value.php